# Turn Off Automatically Hide Scrollbars in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Scrollbars in MS Word are automatically disappearing in Windows 10, which I find annoying. You're supposed to be able to disable this by going to Settings/Ease Of Access/Display in Windows 10. I don't see a Display option in Ease of Access. Is there another way to disable this "feature" ?

Comment: @John I see no scrollbar until I hover over it then it appears.  Is there any way to keep it visible without hovering? I can't imagine why this would not be configurable by the user.

Comment: If the "Ease of Access" window is wide enough, you should see a vertical list on the left. The "Vision" section should be at the top of that list, with "Display" as the first entry.

Comment: Alternatively, in the "Settings" window, you can type `hide scroll` in the searchbox, click on "Automatically hide scroll bars in Windows", and it will take you to the setting (it will have a box around it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two methods for disabling the hiding of scrollbars :

- Run *Settings > Ease of Access > Display* and turn off the option
  "Automatically hide scroll bars in Windows"
- Paste the following text in a `.reg` file and double-click to execute:

  ```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility]
  "DynamicScrollbars"=dword:00000000
  ```